# How to make custom python console

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, cmd, console

So I'm wondering if I can make debugging console that starts when my python script starts and is in another window and shows what python script is doing just so I can debug it easier.  Here's how I thought I could do this Python script outputs --> logs.txt <-- my console script reads and displays the wordings from logs.txt and refreshes every 5s.

Comment: have you looked at https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html, the pdb module?  it might not do exactly what you want, but your current question probably requires very deep python expertise unless I have misread it.  the logging module, https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html, can also be helpful

Comment: i just needing away to make a loging system